# How to get json encoded data using php

Tags: php, json

```
echo $someJSON=json_encode($resultData);
```

output is`{"status":true,"postData":[{"post_id":"3","post_title":"JAVA","post_desc":"JAVA DESCRIPTION","status":"1"},{"post_id":"1","post_title":"PHP API","post_desc":"MAKING PHP API","status":"1"}]}`

From the output, how to get value of 'post_title' using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decode it first using `json_decode`

```
$someJson = json_decode('{"status":true,"postData":[{"post_id":"3","post_title":"JAVA","post_desc":"JAVA DESCRIPTION","status":"1"},{"post_id":"1","post_title":"PHP API","post_desc":"MAKING PHP API","status":"1"}]}');

foreach ($someJson->postData as $data){
    echo $data->post_title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ahsan Ali..

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = json_decode('{"status":true,"postData":[{"post_id":"3","post_title":"JAVA","post_desc":"JAVA DESCRIPTION","status":"1"},{"post_id":"1","post_title":"PHP API","post_desc":"MAKING PHP API","status":"1"}]}');

foreach($arr->postData as $post) {
    $title = $post->post_title;
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: getting Fatal error

Comment: apologies, shouldn't have been in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

`$resultData` is already an object, so you don't need to convert it.
just access its properties like any other objects.
eg:

```
foreach($resultData->postData as $data) {
    echo $data->post_title, ', ';
}
```

demo: http://rextester.com/JHFH10035